# How do I add songs to the Radio?

Tags: fallout-4

I like listening to the Radio in Fallout games. The combination of music with the occasional commentary on my actions is enjoyable. But I'm a little tired of the very small playlist of jokey, often borderline offensive songs. I'd love to replace Diamond City Radio's tunes with some great songs by some of my favorite Boston bands that [fit the spirit of the game.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I8piMHsOya4) It'd be even better if I could *add* them without replacing the existing songs, expanding the overall size of the playlist, to reduce the repetition.

Is it possible to do this? If so, how? I have all of the music that I'd like to use in DRM free MP3 format, as well as the original CD's if I need to rip them to something else.

Comment: are mods an acceptable way of doing it? if so [this](http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/255/) could be helpful

Comment: @Aequitas I expect they'll be necessary, but if they aren't, that'd be preferred.

Comment: Ah I feel you so much. There are like 5-8 Songs only on those Radiostations, looping all the time. They should have taken GTA as an example.

Comment: Even New Vegas had much better radio, if only because there were multiple stations to switch between.

Answer (score 2):

This can be accomplished on PC by simply removing the songs from the game files and placing your own songs in their place. As long as the name is exactly the same, the game will play your songs instead.

To find the music files simply search the Fallout 4 game files for one of the songs: "Heartaches" and "Johnny" are the names of two songs which you can use to search for.

Alternatively you can use [the Custom Radio Music mod](http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/255/?) which essentially does the same as the procedure I outlined above, it only allows you to replace songs and not add any.

Comment: What format do they need to be in?

Comment: the same format as the original files, "XWM". [This skyrim "mod"](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/8303/?) can convert a file to XWM [This skyrim "mod" can convert multiple files](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/3159/?), so can [this program](http://www.techisky.com/how-to/xwm-file-converter.html).